# Laravel Redirect to subdomain before loggin

Tags: redirect, laravel, subdomain

I want to create script that's going to be using different sub-domains as user accounts.

The problem i have is, i would like to create script that's going to be redirecting user just before calling log-in attempt, so the session will be saved on sub-domain, not the main domain.

However, I do not want to share the sessions all around, i want to have it, so one user can be logged on his own sub-domain. So setting up

> ".example.com"

in config file is not way out for me.

**EDIT:**

Routes:
http://pastebin.com/kgaKJCWx

controller:
http://pastebin.com/73xsejG4

view:
http://pastebin.com/W8eWGrNA

Comment: Is the username (subdomain) needed for logging in?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you properly, however the username is going to be the same as the subdomain. If user will logg in with username 'Billy', he's going to be redirected to billy.example.com, and session will be created on that subdomain. Not any other. That's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of would be to just use javascript to adjust the subdomain in the form action attribute. Something along the lines of this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    var username = $(this).find('input[name=username]').val();
    var subdomain = username.toLowerCase(); // you might want to do other things here as well
    var newAction = $(this).prop('action').replace('yourdomain.com', subdomain + '.yourdomain.com');
    $(this).prop('action', newAction);
});
```

So when the form is submitted, before it actually gets sent the action is updated with a subdomain. You could also use a placeholder in your original action and replace that with the actual subdomain.

Comment: Thank you, however it's not working correctly with routes. When I did not add login route yet - it redirected me to correct subdomain, but once I did, it redirects me to %7Busername%7D.example.com/login

I need to update route parameter/argument, but I have no idea how to make it dynamically, since it is php so i can't do this with JS.

Comment: In that case just use a placeholder. Something like: `'route' => array('login', '{username}')` and replace that in JS: `$(this).prop('action').replace('{username}', subdomain)`

Comment: The code you provided works fine, however it seems like laravel framework is updating domain after website reload, because it still does the same - %7Busername%7D.example.com/login.

Comment: i think the only way to make it working is to create another controller method thats going to be including authorisation process, and default postLOGIN method will redirect to that. Which I dont think is the best option. But thank you for your time!

Comment: Note that when using a dynamic subdomain you have to pass the name of the subdomain every time you generate an URL by route name or action.

Comment: I know that, and I am able to pass the subdomain variable after firing the form, inside the controller. But i thought there is better way to do that.

Comment: There might be a way. If you want you can edit your question, add the code you're currently using and I'll see if I find a better/simpler solution...

Comment: Just found I made a mistake in routes file. Thank you, it works as it supposed now!